Historical examples of works that merged different fields of mathematics after analytic geometry
In the 17th century, Descartes and Fermat developed analytic geometry, thereby connecting geometry and algebra. This was a revolution in mathematics that allowed to the solution of geometric problems by algebra (and vice-versa), and paved the way to the development of calculus. So, it seems an interesting thing when a merge of fields happens! Was it the first time a "merger" of fields happened in math? Did it happen again after analytic geometry was developed? When?

You mean like analytic number theory, algebraic geometry, algebraic topology, algebraic combinatorics, differential topology, geometric analysis?

@Conifold: I don't know anything about these fields. I'll read the Wikipedia articles about them, but tomorrow! Thanks.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Something similar happened with mathematics and logic. I think B. Russell and friends tried to make logic (philosophy) the foundation of mathematics which led to the set theory.

@zeynel: which led to the set theory -- Better is "which led to axiomatic set theory", since many aspects of set theory (cardinal and ordinal numbers, applications of the notions of countable and uncountable in real and complex analysis, widespread use of set operations such as union & intersection & Cartesian product, etc.) were well underway for other reasons by the middle of the first decade of the 1900s.
